# SSH to my server fails

Tags: ssh

Assume that my server has 'my' ip. The client is a linux (debian) machine with ip 192.168.15.120. I tried from another machine (Windows) in the same subnet with ip 192.168.15.106. 'my' is a server in the internet with ip 195.xxx.xxx.xxx (certainly out of LAN).
The Windows machine may ssh to my, while I (the linux client) can't.
When in my server I changed the ssh port to 7822, my client could ssh to it.
It seems that something with port 22 on my client is wrong.
What's your opinion? How can I trace the problem and find it?

### Update:

After running ssh -v my I got the following output:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/hamidi/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to my [195.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to my:22 as 'hamidi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:GLEbQGgsPG4q1m5NpQpx1qgfGH+niS93ZQqz/m+amIM
The authenticity of host 'my (195.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:GLEbQGgsPG4q1m5NpQpx1qgfGH+niS93ZQqz/m+amIM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'my,195.xxx.xxx.xxx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XPZJP0PUv/cEg+Z0tsDL6sm8aTEkl/vt+ewJt/RwwH8 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XPZJP0PUv/cEg+Z0tsDL6sm8aTEkl/vt+ewJt/RwwH8 agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hamidi/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
hamidi@my's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to my ([195.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-184-generic x86_64)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my question and embedding the log. I'd tried, but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest tools to debug ssh issues in linux are probably `ssh -v <ip>` and `ssh -vv <ip>`.  You can also combine this with switching the port since you mentioned you were having issues on the default port example: `ssh -v -p 7822 <ip>`

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments you may want to take a look on the server to look at its sshd logs typically located at /var/log/auth.log for ubuntu/debian, perhaps tailing the logs live as you fail to connect with `tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: Also, read the log of your sshd on the server.

Comment: wow it worked! thx
i'm going to update the question to include what ssh -v gave me as an output.

Comment: Now based on the output how can I find that what has been the problem?

Comment: The pastebin from the the original appears to have connected successfully. Is there still an error occuring?

Comment: no, i just like to know what the problem has been?

Comment: I think as @GeraldSchneider said it would be best to go back and look through the historical sshd log on the server, which might show some errors if there was connectivity but some other issue prevented a successful ssh session